# Do I need two Provisioning Profiles?

Tags: ios-provisioning

I've got a Provisioning Profile for distribution com.mycomapnyname.myappname

Now I want to test my app in my iPad and I did all steps- Get certificate - Add my device - create an AppId - and finally create a Development Profile called My Applications (to sets all apps), so I've got a Distribution Profile and a development Profile.

- The bundle identifier for distribution is com.mycomapnyname.myappname
- The bundle identifier for developer  is com.mycomapnyname.*
- In Library Provisioning Profiles I've got both.
- In Ipad Provisioning profile I've got just My Applications Profile

When I try to run it on my iPad I set in Targets - Build Settings:

- Code Signing / Debug / Any iOS SDK = iPhone developer matching with My Applications
- Code Signing / Distribution / Any iOS SDK = iPhone distribution identity

in Targets / Info:

Bundle identifier: com.mycomapnyname.myappname

Finally when I want to run my project (setting to run it on my iPad) I've got the error:

"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

It's a king of mess for me, can anyone help me to be able to run in on my device?

I run other app on my device, but following a tutorial and creating a new app, but I can't run my own app in my device for testing.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't unless you like to setup wild cards for each app which is confusing.
Try this it may help. In xcode go to organizer and then select provisioning profile section. Try to refresh that. It will connect to Dev portal and download your current profiles. Then with your device connected try clicking on the name of the device and make sure your device gets detected by xcode. If it says use for developing click on that and it will also refresh the provisioning profile on your device. That should re sync everything. If this dies not work let me know and I'll get on my Mac and see how I can help you more.
Adrian

Comment: Ok I did that, I refreshed and everytinhg was updated...My Team Name (which wasn't before). I got an alert caution message "No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'."  I connected my device and Xcode detected it by showing the green dot, and on Applications says TestingApp (which was the one on the tutorial).   I didn't understand "If it says use for developing" where exactly?

Comment: What I saw also in the Organizer is that I've got two TEAMS, "JOHN SMITH" for Distribution and "jhon smith" for Development. In Library Provisioning Profiles both profiles I've got are under JOHN SMITH team. And in the iPad Provisioning Profiles the development profile that I created today is linked also to JOHN SMITH. Shouldn't it be linked to "john smith" as it is for development? How do I do that? I dind'f find "Use for developingt" anywhere :( Thanks in advance

Comment: The green shows that your device is connected. Right in the middle of the screen it should show your profile from your phone. That is in the organizer. If you don't see that then you should ask it to be used for development. Check your profiles on the Dev portal as well to make sure that they have been synced with xcode. In the portal in profiles on the right side it should say managed by xcode. I am away from my computer now but in about an hour I can log in and set up step by step if the above didn't work.

Comment: You may have to check the number of profiles you currently have in Dev portal. There may be one too many in there. If so delete the extra one and refresh again. That could be also a solution. Adrian

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I went to the Dev portal and checked that. It doesn't say. I tryed also Add it to Portal from the organizer and I've got the same message: "No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'." I guess here is the problem... I'll be on my computer by the time you are logged again. I'll wait. Thanks

Comment: In the Dev portal, I've got one for development and one for distribution. In Devices, the associated profile to my iPad is the development.

Comment: Are they both under the same name? If they are then go back to xcode and delete both of your profiles there and refresh. Sometimes during download xcode does not get it right. I see your comment below. Both dist and Dev has to be the same.

Comment: no, one is called my app name (the distribution one) and the other My Applications (the development one). And, of course, I can't associate the distribution one to the iPad, just the development. I wish I could upload screenshots, but I only have 5 in my reputation score :(